# Cheapest hotel in Europe

Tags: europe, budget, hotels, where-on-earth, factoids

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qTE7bapkTw) a hotel in Belarus is shown with rooms for $4.10 per night. But the city is not mentioned. So, is this the cheapest hotel in Europe and where is it located?

Comment: Could "Where are the cheapest hotels in Europe located?" be a better title for the question?

Answer (score 8):

No, it is not the cheapest hotel in Europe.

There is no clear definition of the difference between e.g. hotels, hostels and bed & breakfasts, but it is not difficult to find cheaper hotel-like lodging on booking.com in other European countries. I just tried a search in Ukraine for an arbitrary date in October and found about 60 offers for €4 per night or less.

I would also assume that many of the cheaper offers are not even advertising on the better-known booking sites, since it is too expensive. In Ukraine, there is e.g. *very* cheap lodging available on most train and larger bus stations, but you will not be able to book these online.

The hotel shown in the video is *Zhilkommunhoza* in Krasnapolle. That was already answered in comments to the YouTube video.

Comment: What site did you search on for those offers? Did you search in English?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Are you asking about the offers I already stated that I found on booking.com. No, I did not use booking.com in English, but I don't think that they show search results depending on the user interface language.

Comment: I ask because I didn’t find that on booking.com, the cheapest listings were dorm beds which are hostel accommodation, not a hotel room.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Most of the cheapest listings are just for a bed in a dormitory, but there are several options for a private room. For example a private room in Hostel №2 in Alchevsʼk is UAH 54 per night, or about USD 2.10. Even if this is a hostel, I would consider a private room 'hotel-like' enough to be comparable.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if the hotel is the cheapest in Europe, but I found one for $4.80 a night called the Old Road Apartments, [link](https://www.booking.com/hotel/by/old-roads-apartments.en-gb.html?aid=356983&label=gog235jc-1FCAsoJUINYmVsYXJ1cy1taW5za0gzWANoUIgBAZgBCbgBB8gBDdgBAegBAfgBDIgCAagCA7gCqYGs6wXAAgE&sid=ac71c7e02e4bdf38563cac7fbb772806&all_sr_blocks=128189501_198896970_1_42_0&checkin=2019-10-30&checkout=2019-10-31&dest_id=20&dest_type=country&group_adults=1&group_children=0&hapos=1&highlighted_blocks=128189501_198896970_1_42_0&hpos=1&no_rooms=1&req_adults=1&req_children=0&room1=A&sr_order=price&srepoch=1567293853&srpvid=f660a48e9609029d&ucfs=1&bhgwe_cep=1&from=searchresults;highlight_room=;has_campaign_deals_offpeak19_customer_label=1#hotelTmpl). (Not affiliated with the service). Or the cheapest in Belarus classified as a hotel is [Райский сад](https://www.booking.com/hotel/by/raiskii-sad.en-gb.html?aid=356983&label=gog235jc-1FCAsoJUINYmVsYXJ1cy1taW5za0gzWANoUIgBAZgBCbgBB8gBDdgBAegBAfgBDIgCAagCA7gCqYGs6wXAAgE&sid=ac71c7e02e4bdf38563cac7fbb772806&all_sr_blocks=547974606_199579196_1_0_0&checkin=2019-10-30&checkout=2019-10-31&dest_id=20&dest_type=country&group_adults=1&group_children=0&hapos=2&highlighted_blocks=547974606_199579196_1_0_0&hpos=2&no_rooms=1&req_adults=1&req_children=0&room1=A&sr_order=price&srepoch=1567293853&srpvid=f660a48e9609029d&ucfs=1&from=searchresults;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl) for $4.99.